# Is it possible to get a visa to the UK while unemployed?

Tags: visas, uk

I am an unemployed Belorussian girl and wish to travel to the UK to spend the summer with my boyfriend. He usually visits me every month using the 5-day visa waiver program they have over here, and it's my dream to visit him in return.

Since I am unemployed it is difficult to provide supporting documents and I will be relying entirely on my sponsors. My mother who is a police woman in Belarus, and my boyfriend who is self-employed. He earns a decent amount of money and can easily support me in the UK, but I have seen many cases where the visa is refused because the applicant cannot provide sufficient proof of their intent in visiting.

Is there even a point in applying since I have no job or anything really? I have no income and my boyfriend will be paying for the tickets, food etc.

Comment: Everything you stated about your circumstances suggests someone who would want to overstay their visa. Can you do anything to change that, such as getting a job or becoming a student full time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will be extremely difficult.

Based on the facts you've explained here, the Entry Clearance Officer processing your application will reason that if he lets you in, there will be essentially no good reason why you would *want* go back to Belarus instead of staying with your boyfriend in the UK. That is exactly the circumstance where he is *supposed to* deny a visa.

In all probability, applying for a visa in those circumstances will just be a way to lose the application fee, as well as get a pesky yellow-to-orange flag in your immigration history.

You would need to wait until you're in circumstances where you're more solidly rooted in your home country.  Or, you could (plan to) marry and apply for a permit for you to settle with him permanently -- that's not easy to get either, but maybe not quite as hopeless as a visitor visa.

Comment: Assuming it's illegal to overstay a visa, wouldn't "not wanting to break the law and risk jeopardizing future trips" be considered a good reason for wanting to go back to Belarus? It seems a bit unfair to assume every visa-seeking person is an opportunistic criminal. (not your assumption, but border patrol's)

Comment: @EdmundReed: If wanting to obey the law was sufficient to make travelers obey it, there wouldn't be any point in requiring them to apply for visas in the first place. The visa officer's job is to ensure there is something _more than that_.